# Nextjs web page not displaying suspense fallback without using react's experimental use hook

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm developing a web application utilizing Next.js (v14.1.3) for SSR with React(v18.2.0).I want to use next.js Suspense to display a skeleton via fallback during fetching the data necessary on the client-side but I cannot make fallback displayed. There is just a blank space instead. But I ensured that skeleton css and html is fine.

Here is the simplified code sample. I set diseases setAuth inside useEffect by fetching the necessary data from firebase functions and pass it to the child component DiseaseTagList:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import { Functions, httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import styles from './styles.module.css';
import { Suspense, useState } from 'react';
const IconButton = dynamic(() => import('../../components/IconButton'));
const Shimmer = dynamic(() => import('../../components/Shimmer'));
const Button = dynamic(() => import('../../components/Button'));
const Sidebar = dynamic(() => import('../../components/Sidebar'));
const Background = dynamic(() => import('../../components/Background'));
const DiseaseTagList = dynamic(() => import('../../components/DiseaseTagList'));
const BranchList = dynamic(() => import('../../components/BranchList'));
import Head from "next/head";
import { Settings } from '../../utils/helpers';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import  FirebaseService from '../../config/firebase';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const firebaseSingleton = FirebaseService.Instance;
  const functions = firebaseSingleton.Functions || {} as Functions;
  const getCategories = httpsCallable(functions, 'getCategories');
  var categories = await getCategories().then((categoriesData: any) => {return categoriesData.data});
  return {props:{categories}};
}

function QuestionsAndAnswers(props: { categories }) {
  const {categories} = props;
  const [isSidebarVisible, setIsSidebarVisible] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const [diseases, setDiseases] = useState();
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const firebaseSingleton = FirebaseService.Instance;
    const functions = firebaseSingleton.Functions || {};

    const getMostAskedDiseaseTagsAsync = async () => {
      const getMostAskedDiseaseTags = httpsCallable(
        functions,
        'getMostAskedDiseaseTags'
      );
      await getMostAskedDiseaseTags().then((diseasesData: any) => {
        setDiseases(diseasesData.data);
      });
    }
    getMostAskedDiseaseTagsAsync();
  }, []);

  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    setIsSidebarVisible(!isSidebarVisible);
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <div       
        className="home-container pt-2 qa-home-container question-detail-page">
        <div className="qa-page">
          <div className="hamburgerMenu pt-2 home-item text-center">
            <Sidebar
              onToggleSidebar={toggleSidebar}
              isSidebarVisible={isSidebarVisible}
            ></Sidebar>
          </div>
          <div className="questions-and-answers">
            <div className={styles["qa-parent-container"]}>
              <div className="go-back-btn">
                <IconButton
                  size="Medium"
                  variant="Secondary"
                  iconName="Back"
                  onClick={() => router.push('/')}
                ></IconButton>
              </div>
              <div className={styles["qa-wrapper"]}>
                <h1>Questions</h1>

                    <Suspense fallback={                        
                    <>
                      <Shimmer type="Text" />
                      <Shimmer type="Text" />
                      <Shimmer type="Text" />
                      <Shimmer type="Text" />
                      <Shimmer type="Text" />
                    </>}>
                    
                      <DiseaseTagList diseases={diseases()}/>
                    </Suspense>
                  <BranchList categories={categories}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default QuestionsAndAnswers;
```

And here is the DiseaseTagList component which is pretty straightforward:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import styles from '../../pages/QuestionAndAnswers/styles.module.css';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { transformUrl } from 'src/utils/helpers';


function DiseaseTagList({diseases}) {  
return(
  <div className={styles["qa-container"]}>
  <div className={styles["diseases-container"]}>
    {
      diseases && (diseases as []).map((item: any, i: number) => 
      (
        <div key={i} className={styles["disease"]}>
          <Link href={`/${transformUrl(item.name)}/hastalik/${item.id}?p=1&fromInternal=true`}>{item.name}</Link > 
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
</div>
)}

export default DiseaseTagList;
```

I cannot figure out the problem. Could it be firebase functions? Or is it getServerSideProps function or dynamic imports?

Strange thing, if I install react and react-dom experimental and apply the new use hook: when I pass the Promise (which fetches the data from firebase) to child component and run the Promise via use hook, Suspense fallback (skeleton) works as expected.